Keycloak 25 (Quarkus) - Alias Cert passwords do not work
I have just finished upgrading from an earlier, Wildfly based, keycloak to Keycloak 25 (Quarkus based). I have everything working except the keystore. We are using a P12 keystore containing a certificate (alias?) bound to a different password from the keystore itself.
I have noticed that the default properties provided by keycloak do not provide this option so I took the approach of using the quarkus properties.
I have attempted to use these properties:
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=<p12 path>
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-password=<password>
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-alias=<alias cert name>
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-alias-password=<different password>

I have also tried:
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-key-alias=<alias cert name>
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-key-password=<different password>

When I set these, the keycloak instance always fails with:
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption

I have verified this password and actually used the clipboard to paste it to avoid human error. How do I get the keycloak instance to work in this setup?

I figured it out!
The documentation is incorrect if you follow it to the letter...
The quarkus and keycloak properties are deliberately separated and cannot be set in the same config file. (Found this in a pull request)
The docs state to define a quarkus.properties file and place it in the conf directory. Once you do this, the docs also state to set this param --config-file. DON'T SET THIS CONFIG PARAM, it overrides your other settings if present in the keycloak.conf.
I have the https-key-store-file and https-key-store-file-password set in the keycloak.conf. I then defined an empty file named quarkus.properties in my keycloak conf directory. Inside this file I placed
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-alias=<alias cert name>
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-alias-password=<different password>

I also placed the management console versions of these params in there.
With that, I started KC.bat with the build flag and then started it. Everything started correctly now with differing passwords from my keystore to the certificate alias.
